# Why the scroll bar is ignored on my div with overflow-x=scroll?

Tags: html, css

I have a div on my html that I want to apply a laterla scroll.

This is the html

```
<div class="section-container mt-5 row"  >
     <div class="section" v-for="(item,index) in board.sections" v-bind:key="index">
          <div class="card-title">
               <h5 class="text-center section-header">{{item.name}}</h5>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And this is the css im using:

```
.section-container{
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.section{
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

I read in another post that this should do the trick with the lateral scrolling, but it is ignored, my divs just keep stacking on the same div. I'm applying it wrong? They should be aligned horizontaly and scroll through all of them.

[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRFbP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using bootstrap. The bootstrap class `row` makes the element a `flex-box` with `flex-wrap: wrap`. This causes your element to wrap to the next row instead of flowing out of the container.

Add a rule in your section-container class to prevent flex-child wrapping.

```
.section-container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
}
```

Also, you might need to set flex-basis or min-width on the children if you want them to have a minimum width.

I suggest you read more about flex-box. [This](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) can help you get started.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much!